# Javascript library to manage translation forms

Tags: javascript, jquery, tinymce, translation, user-experience

Is anybody aware of any javascript tool (compatible with jQuery, tinymce or any other clientside library) able to manage the following requirements?

I need to show translation forms in which every field (either input or textarea) could contain some segment variables or code sections (mostly HTML).

For example:

```
"Hello {{firstname}}, this is your personal page."
```

or

```
"You improved your personal score of <strong>{{n}} points</strong>."
```

Of course I obtain these segments from a template parser and I need to show them to a set of translators that will perform localization towards many languages. **I know that in many cases I can (and should!) avoid variables and code inside translation segments, but in many other cases I really can't**.

The problem is: I would like to manage coherence about variables and code directly on the browser (I trust my translators but a bit more of UI/UX help is always a good thing!).

A nice approach could be providing the set of variables and code tags, ready to be inserted by means of a single click (in order to avoid mispelled variables or incorrect code syntax) and a bit of pre-submit validation to be sure everything was inserted.

I've seen this approach in other websites, such as *Facebook* or *Freelancer.com* (who have the power and the ability to reimplement the whole thing from scratch!).
Do you know about any *almost-ready* tool/library for this purpose?

Thank you all in advance for any suggestion.

Answer (score -1):

If you are asking for a library to translate text - here is Google Translate API: https://developers.google.com/translate/?csw=1

If you are asking for a library which can take user input, perform validation, and insert into the DOM - then Jquery has everything you need.

If you are asking for something else, let me know and I'll edit my question.

Comment: Please read again my question, I was asking about a specific client-side functionality (eventually based on jQuery) to handle "syntactic" validation of translation segments in a form.

Comment: Your question does not mention validation, thank you for clarifying though!

Is there any reason why you wouldn't just use jquery and regexp's?

Comment: My question mentions validation, indeed. Please read questions more carefully. I'm looking for a tool or a jQuery plugin as an almost-ready solution (or at least a base from which I can start). I DO NOT need to automatically translate stuff, I need a browser-based tool for my translators. I know I can implement it myself (with jQuery, regex and everything), but that's quite a challenging task.

Comment: Hmmm, ok! Well maybe this library can handle your variable validations for you: http://rickharrison.github.io/validate.js/

Thank you for taking the time to explain - if I'm still completely off base then maybe consider rephrasing your question to make it more accessible. Good luck!